# textscan strange behavior

Tags: matlab, file-io, cell-array

I want to read a text file of the form:

```
gatcgtacgtcgatgc
gtcgtacgatcgcatg 
cagctgactgatcgatcg
```

. So each line is a string, and the delimiter is `\n.`
Suppose this file is called `'data.txt'`.
I would think

```
fid = fopen('data.txt')
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n')
fclose('data.txt')
```

Would give me 3x1 cell with `C{1} = 'gatcg....' , C{2} = 'gtcgt....' and C{3} = 'cagctg....'`.

This is not the case. It tells me `C = {3x1 cell}`. However, I get the following behavior:

```
C{1}

ans = 

   'gatc...'

   'gtcg...'

   'cagc...'

C{2} 
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions

C{3}
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

What is going on here? o_O

Comment: BTW the call to FCLOSE should be: `fclose(fid)`

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following first:

```
C =  C{1};

%# then you can use
C{1}
C{2}
C{3}
```

Thats because in your case, TEXTSCAN returns a 1-by-1 cell array C, where its first elements is a three-elements cell array.

Answer (score 0):

The output of [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) is a cell array which itself contains arrays of the various data inputs. In your case, all of the data is stuffed into a single cell array. To access each entry do this:

```
>> C = textscan(fid, '%s');
>> C{1}{1}

ans =

gatcgtacgtcgatgc

>> C{1}{2}

ans =

gtcgtacgatcgcatg

>> C{1}{3}

ans =

cagctgactgatcgatcg
```

Note that you don't need to indicate `\n` as a delimiter as that is the default end of line character.